# Download and save pdf into files from url in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am downloading pdf from url and saving to .documentsDirectory. but it's saving somewhere inside app data, instead I want to save it on phone.

```
    func downnload(url: NSURL, filename:String) {
        
        let fileName = String((url.lastPathComponent!)) as NSString
        let documentsUrl:URL =  (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL?)!
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")
        
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = URLRequest(url:url as URL)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                    do {
                        let contents  = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
                        for indexx in 0..<contents.count {
                            if contents[indexx].lastPathComponent == destinationFileUrl.lastPathComponent {
                                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
                                self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (let err) {
                        print("error: \(err)")
                    }
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file in to Apples' Files App using UIDocumentInteractionController

After downloading pdf from url and saving to .documentsDirectory, Give your documentsDirectory file url to UIDocumentInteractionController

```
let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

documentInteractionController.url = url //Here is your documentsDirectory file url 
documentInteractionController.uti = url.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data, public.content"
documentInteractionController.name = url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent
documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
```

Here I'm using extension for URL

```
extension URL {
  var typeIdentifier: String? {
    return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier
  }
  var localizedName: String? {
    return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName
  }
}
```